# The verb "Add" in the passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

I wonder if it is correct to say:

> Twenty added by two equals twenty-two.

Comment: You have the wrong preposition. "Twenty added **to** two equals twenty-two," or "Twenty **plus** two equals twenty-two."

Comment: I think you have a confusion about prepositions and what the passive voice is.   The passive voice would be "Twenty **is added** by..."   Yes, you can use *add* in the passive voice: *The milk **was added** to the batter **by** Joe.  But in your example, "two" isn't a person or thing that's doing the adding.

Answer (score 1):

Twenty plus two equals twenty-two.
Two plus twenty equals twenty-two.

In **addition  in arithmetic**, the verb is to add but when there are two or more numbers in the **operation known as addition** where the operation is written with one number on top of another with a plus sign, we use the word plus and the number. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce 25 + 26 vertically on this page.

Of course, you can also say: When 2 is added to 20, the result is 22. But that is not the usual way to express it when, for example, explaining arithmetic or talking about adding number. In Romance languages, the verb add cannot just be translated as add in English. It becomes one number plus another number. I believe that is the source of confusion here.

The passive of the verb to add is to be added: When 2 is added to 20, you get 22. **Yes, that can be said or written but it would not be usual.**